# How to tell if an ajax timer has gone off at page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have a web application and I'm attempting to put an ajax timer control in it to give me a post back every 10-20 seconds. (possibly longer depending on performance). I have a lot of dynamically created each with auto postback. These controls are inside of their own update panel.

Well, whenever an AJAX timer `tick` happens, I want to be able to know this at page_load so that I can have some conditions off of this(such as not creating some controls or whatever).

So how can I know at Page_Load time that the reason for the post back was a `tick` event? I have tried doing something like `if(Request.Form[mytimer.UniqueID]!=null)` but that is always a false condition(it is always null)

Basically, I just want to know if an AJAX timer tick event will happen, before the event actually occurs(which is after page_load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023533/http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx)

The article explains how to figure out which control caused the post back which in your case would be your timer control.